# Forming SQL/LINQ query - Ordered elements across different rows sharing logical grouping

Tags: c#, sql, linq

This will be a bit abstract but I have a method like this:

```
private int[] ReturnLogicalGroupingAForOrderedElements(List<int> elements) {
    //sql query or linq query
    //returns an int[] in case there are more than one matching set.
}
```

Let's say the List passed contains the following  elements: 3,6 and 9. I need to find the exact same list, elements in the same order, sharing the same logical grouping (whatever it is), from a datatable source.

I have a datatable with the following columns (all of them int values):

```
LogicalGroupingA, LogicalGroupingB, Element, ElementOrder
```

I need to find and identify that all of the above elements (3,6,9) exists across several rows, sharing the same logical grouping. Example:

```
7,1,3,1
7,1,6,2
7,1,9,3
```

If all of these are found then I want to return the value from LogicalGroupingA which is 7.
But consider this, there might be a different set of rows (sharing same logicalgrouping) that are:

```
4,1,3,1
4,1,6,2
4,1,9,3
4,1,5,4
```

The query should only return the desired value if the complete series of elements is exactly what is asked for (here the first three elements are equal to the list queried for but since there's a fourth element here it is not equal). Assume that the datatable rows are mixed. LogicalGroupingA can contain many of LogicalGroupingB which again can contain many Elements.

Originally I had a very simple datatable setup where a colum contained a string like "3,6,9" that I would have to parse in my logic. The aim by creating this new numeric datatable was to make it as fast as possible (in theory). I'm open for an alternative datatable structure if it can improve on this but mainly I'm asking for help forming the desired query (sql or linq) for the above table.

EDIT: Maybe a bit bad timing posting the question as I will be gone from my dev machine for the next two days but rest assure I will give the proper points & votes (and comments) once I am back and have tested the suggestions. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: So you're looking for not only the the proper grouping but also the order?

Comment: If you run the comparison, and there are two sets of matching groups as you describe (LogicalGroupingA = 4 and 7), what exactly do you expect to happen? Should that method perhaps be returning say an IEnumerable<DataSet> with the results starting with 7 in the first DataSet of the IEnumerable and those starting with 4 in the second DataSet? You say that for the 4 block the 4th element doesn't match so it doesn't match, but what if that 4th element wasn't there and it was an exact match?

Comment: code4life: The order must match yes. The rows can be randomly scattered but (in the above example) value 3 must be order 1. Value 6 order 2. Value 9 order 3. 3-6-9. The actual rows containing these values however might come in a totally different order from each other.

Comment: Nanhydrin: Thanks for pointing that out. You assume correctly. If there was indeed to be found two matching sets then I would return them both in an IEnumerable. I have edited the example method to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Grouping
{
   public int LGA{get;set;}
   public int LGB{get;set;}
   public int El {get;set;}
   public int ElO {get;set;}
}

void Main()
{
    var dbValues = new List<Grouping>
        {
            new Grouping { LGA =7, LGB = 1, El=6, ElO=2 },
            new Grouping { LGA =7, LGB = 1, El=3, ElO=1 },
            new Grouping { LGA =4, LGB = 1, El=3, ElO=1 },
            new Grouping { LGA =4, LGB = 1, El=6, ElO=2 },
            new Grouping { LGA =4, LGB = 1, El=7, ElO=3 },
        };
    var dbGroups = dbValues.Select(dbData => new {Group = dbData.LGA, Element = dbData.El, ElO = dbData.ElO})
            .OrderBy(item => item.ElO)
            .GroupBy(item => item.Group);
    var elements = new List<int>{3, 6};

    foreach(var dbGroup in dbGroups)
    {
        if (dbGroup.Select(el => el.Element).SequenceEqual(elements))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dbGroup.First().Group);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this assumes that the order of the Groupings is maintained in the GroupBy. I think you can not assume this when dealing with sql.

Comment: @Firo: can you elaborate a little bit more what you mean?

Comment: you are using Linq-to-objects here with its implementation of groupby which presumably adds the Elements in the order in which they come from the orderby and stores it in a datastrcuture which preserves this order so the sequenceequals will hold. As the OP asks for sql as well i assumed he wants to use some sql-linqprovider which translates into sql. And since sql does not execute the orderby befor the grouping and it does not give you the guarantee that it will maintain any order except the the one applied at last.

Comment: @Firo: can you provide a reference to that statement? I'm going to move the OrderBy in the foreach, but would like to know where from it comes. Thanks.

Comment: i just tested it with NHibernate Linq provider which even can't translate the linq-statement to sql. regarding the order: in one of my projects i was bitten by the "randomly" returned records. two identical selects returned the records in different order

Comment: This suggestion worked for me. My final piece of code looks something like this:
var dbGroups = _table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => 
          new {LGA = row.Field<int>("coLGA"), LGB = row.Field<int>("coLGB"), EL = row.Field<int>("coEL"), Order = row.Field<int>("coELO")})
          .OrderBy(row => row.Order)
          .GroupBy(row => new {row.LGA, row.LGB});

Parallel.ForEach(dbGroups, group => ProcessGroup(group));

Answer (score 0):

Update: filter the groups with more than the specified elements

assuming the 4 columns are unique

```
SELECT
    LogicalGroupingA
FROM
(
    -- get all Groupings that have the specified order
    SELECT
      LogicalGroupingA, LogicalGroupingB
    FROM
      table
    WHERE
      (element = :listelement1 AND ElementOrder = 1) OR
      (element = :listelement2 AND ElementOrder = 2) OR
      ...
    GROUP BY
      LogicalGroupingA, LogicalGroupingB
    HAVING
      COUNT(*) = :listcount
) as candidates
WHERE
    -- filter all Groupings that have more than the specified elements
    Count(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE LogicalGroupingA = candidates.LogicalGroupingA AND LogicalGroupingB = candidates.LogicalGroupingB) = :listcount
```

as LINQ, don't know if every Linqprovider understands it

```
public class Row
{
   public int GroupA { get; set; }
   public int GroupB { get; set; }
   public int Element { get; set; }
   public int ElementOrder { get; set; }
}

private IEnumerable<int> ReturnLogicalGroupingAForOrderedElements(IList<int> elements)
{
    Expression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Row), "x");
    Expression propElement = Expression.Property(parameter, "Element");
    Expression propElementOrder = Expression.Property(parameter, "ElementOrder");
    Expression where;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
    {
        var restriction = Expression.AndAlso(
            Expression.Equal(propElement, elements[i]),
            Expression.Equal(propElementOrder, i + 1));

        if (where == null)
            where = restriction;
        else
            where = Expression.Or(where, restriction);
    }

    var groupsWithSameOrder = Rows.Where(where)
        .GroupBy(r => new { r.GroupA, r.GroupB })
        .Where(g => g.Count() == elements.Count)
        .Select(g => g.Key);

    return groupsWithSameOrder.Except(Rows
            .Where(r => groupsWithSameOrder.Contains(new { r.GroupA, r.GroupB }))
            .GroupBy(r => new { r.GroupA, r.GroupB })
            .Where(g => g.Count() != elements.Count)
            .Select(g => g.Key))
        .Select(key => key.GroupA);
}
```

Comment: I am trying this with SQL but it's returning values for lists that are larger. If I'm looking for the list '3-6-9' I write the above as:

SELECT logicalGroupingA
FROM table
WHERE (element = 3 AND order = 1) OR
(element = 6 AND order = 2) OR
(element = 9 AND order = 3)
GROUP BY
logicalGroupingA, logicalGroupingB
HAVING
COUNT(*) = 3

I have two list entries in the table:
1,1,3,1-
1,1,6,2-
1,1,9,3-
2,2,3,1-
2,2,6,2-
2,2,9,3-
2,2,5,4-

In this case it returns both 1 and 2 when it should only return 1.